Magento 2.4.6 Preselect Magento 2 Product Custom Options based on URL Parameters
I have a product with custom options like Color and Size.
When users visit a product page with a URL like https://example.com/product.html?color=Red&size=Small, I want the Color option to be preselected as "Red" and the Size option as "Small" automatically.
I need guidance on how to:

Retrieve the values from the URL parameters (color and size).
Use JavaScript/jQuery to preselect these options dynamically on page load.
Ensure that the preselected options reflect in the dropdown selects or radio buttons on the Magento 2 product page.


You can use this as an example. I implemented it for the default Luma theme, where we have swatches.

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.urlParam = function(name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return results ? decodeURIComponent(results[1]) : null;
    }
    function selectAttribute(attribute) {
        var value = jQuery.urlParam(attribute);
        if (value) {
            var el = jQuery("[data-attribute-code='" + attribute + "']").find(".swatch-attribute-options").find("[data-option-label='" + value + "']");
            if (!el.hasClass("selected") && !el.hasClass("disabled")) {
                el.trigger('click');
            }
            return el;
        }
        return null;
    }

    var elColor = selectAttribute('color');
    var elSize = selectAttribute('size');
    
    console.log('Default Select', elColor, elSize);
});

